# Calling Data from External Provider but can't display desired Data

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, provider

I'm stuck. I'm calling an external ASP that provides sports odds data(currently coded for NBA) which I'm displaying through a dynamic text field on my stage. I was able to get the current day and which "team vs team" will to display. Below the "team vs team" I want the to display the "points spread" and "points total". I'm confused now how to call the two types of data I want from the document so just those two display. Below is my XML and below that is the Flash AS3 code. Any help would be much appreciated, THANKS! (I hope my explanation helps)

I can't attach a screen shot, but basically, when it runs, the text field right now looks like this:

Game for Dec. 13
team vs. team
team vs. team
team vs. team

what I want it to display:

Game for Dec. 13
team vs. team
(points spread) (points total)
team vs. team
(points spread) (points total)
team vs. team
(points spread) (points total)

//<<<<<<<<<<<<<<(XML)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<livefeedlines leagues="nba" periods="0" scores="N" popindex="Y" fromminutes="5" begindate="null" enddate="null" store="DEPOSIT">
    <paramstr generator="ASP" generated="2012-12-12T15:45:32-08:00">'', '', '''nba''', '', '0', 'Y', 'B', 'N', 'Y', 5, -1, '', null, null, 'date asc', 0, 'DEPOSIT'</paramstr>
    <game id="48037935" sporttype="Basketball" league="NBA" gamedate="2012-12-12T16:05:00-08:00" gamedow="4" status="O" team1rotnum="701" team1name="Brooklyn Nets" team1pitcher="" team2rotnum="702" team2name="Toronto Raptors" team2pitcher="" ontv="N" channel="" order="5">
        <line periodnum="0" perioddesc="Game" periodwagercutoff="2012-12-12T16:10:00-08:00" store="DEPOSIT" favoredteam="Brooklyn Nets">
            <spread points="-7" team1adj="-110" team2adj="-110" puckline="" circled="N"/>
            <total points="185" team1adj="-110" team2adj="-110" circled="N"/>
            <money team1line="-325" team2line="265" drawline="0" circled="N"/>
            <popularity index="5"/>
        </line>
    </game>
    <game id="48037936" sporttype="Basketball" league="NBA" gamedate="2012-12-12T16:05:00-08:00" gamedow="4" status="O" team1rotnum="703" team1name="Atlanta Hawks" team1pitcher="" team2rotnum="704" team2name="Orlando Magic" team2pitcher="" ontv="N" channel="" order="5">
        <line periodnum="0" perioddesc="Game" periodwagercutoff="2012-12-12T16:10:00-08:00" store="DEPOSIT" favoredteam="Atlanta Hawks">
            <spread points="-5" team1adj="-110" team2adj="-110" puckline="" circled="N"/>
            <total points="189.5" team1adj="-110" team2adj="-110" circled="N"/>
            <money team1line="-200" team2line="170" drawline="0" circled="N"/>
            <popularity index="4"/>
        </line>
    </game>
    <game id="48037937" sporttype="Basketball" league="NBA" gamedate="2012-12-12T16:05:00-08:00" gamedow="4" status="O" team1rotnum="705" team1name="Cleveland Cavaliers" team1pitcher="" team2rotnum="706" team2name="Indiana Pacers" team2pitcher="" ontv="N" channel="" order="5">
        <line periodnum="0" perioddesc="Game" periodwagercutoff="2012-12-12T16:10:00-08:00" store="DEPOSIT" favoredteam="Indiana Pacers">
            <spread points="-7.5" team1adj="-110" team2adj="-110" puckline="" circled="N"/>
            <total points="189" team1adj="-110" team2adj="-110" circled="N"/>
            <money team1line="290" team2line="-350" drawline="0" circled="N"/>
            <popularity index="6"/>
        </line>
    </game>
    <game id="48037938" sporttype="Basketball" league="NBA" gamedate="2012-12-12T16:35:00-08:00" gamedow="4" status="O" team1rotnum="707" team1name="Chicago Bulls" team1pitcher="" team2rotnum="708" team2name="Philadelphia 76ers" team2pitcher="" ontv="N" channel="" order="5">
        <line periodnum="0" perioddesc="Game" periodwagercutoff="2012-12-12T16:40:00-08:00" store="DEPOSIT" favoredteam="Philadelphia 76ers">
            <spread points="-2" team1adj="-110" team2adj="-110" puckline="" circled="N"/>
            <total points="180.5" team1adj="-110" team2adj="-110" circled="N"/>
            <money team1line="113" team2line="-133" drawline="0" circled="N"/>
            <popularity index="9"/>
        </line>
    </game>
    <game id="48037939" sporttype="Basketball" league="NBA" gamedate="2012-12-12T16:35:00-08:00" gamedow="4" status="O" team1rotnum="709" team1name="Los Angeles Clippers" team1pitcher="" team2rotnum="710" team2name="Charlotte Bobcats" team2pitcher="" ontv="N" channel="" order="5">
        <line periodnum="0" perioddesc="Game" periodwagercutoff="2012-12-12T16:40:00-08:00" store="DEPOSIT" favoredteam="Los Angeles Clippers">
            <spread points="-8" team1adj="-110" team2adj="-110" puckline="" circled="N"/>
            <total points="200.5" team1adj="-110" team2adj="-110" circled="N"/>
            <money team1line="-400" team2line="320" drawline="0" circled="N"/>
            <popularity index="3"/>
        </line>
    </game>
    <game id="48037940" sporttype="Basketball" league="NBA" gamedate="2012-12-12T16:35:00-08:00" gamedow="4" status="O" team1rotnum="711" team1name="Golden State Warriors" team1pitcher="" team2rotnum="712" team2name="Miami Heat" team2pitcher="" ontv="N" channel="" order="5">
        <line periodnum="0" perioddesc="Game" periodwagercutoff="2012-12-12T16:40:00-08:00" store="DEPOSIT" favoredteam="Miami Heat">
            <spread points="-8" team1adj="-110" team2adj="-110" puckline="" circled="N"/>
            <total points="205" team1adj="-110" team2adj="-110" circled="N"/>
            <money team1line="310" team2line="-380" drawline="0" circled="N"/>
            <popularity index="1"/>
        </line>
    </game>
    <game id="48037941" sporttype="Basketball" league="NBA" gamedate="2012-12-12T17:05:00-08:00" gamedow="4" status="O" team1rotnum="713" team1name="Denver Nuggets" team1pitcher="" team2rotnum="714" team2name="Minnesota Timberwolves" team2pitcher="" ontv="N" channel="" order="5">
        <line periodnum="0" perioddesc="Game" periodwagercutoff="2012-12-12T17:10:00-08:00" store="DEPOSIT" favoredteam="Minnesota Timberwolves">
            <spread points="-4" team1adj="-110" team2adj="-110" puckline="" circled="N"/>
            <total points="200" team1adj="-110" team2adj="-110" circled="N"/>
            <money team1line="151" team2line="-171" drawline="0" circled="N"/>
            <popularity index="12"/>
        </line>
    </game>
    <game id="48037942" sporttype="Basketball" league="NBA" gamedate="2012-12-12T17:05:00-08:00" gamedow="4" status="O" team1rotnum="715" team1name="Sacramento Kings" team1pitcher="" team2rotnum="716" team2name="Milwaukee Bucks" team2pitcher="" ontv="N" channel="" order="5">
        <line periodnum="0" perioddesc="Game" periodwagercutoff="2012-12-12T17:10:00-08:00" store="DEPOSIT" favoredteam="Milwaukee Bucks">
            <spread points="-8" team1adj="-110" team2adj="-110" puckline="" circled="N"/>
            <total points="198" team1adj="-110" team2adj="-110" circled="N"/>
            <money team1line="290" team2line="-350" drawline="0" circled="N"/>
            <popularity index="13"/>
        </line>
    </game>
    <game id="48037943" sporttype="Basketball" league="NBA" gamedate="2012-12-12T17:05:00-08:00" gamedow="4" status="O" team1rotnum="717" team1name="New Orleans Hornets" team1pitcher="" team2rotnum="718" team2name="Oklahoma City Thunder" team2pitcher="" ontv="N" channel="" order="5">
        <line periodnum="0" perioddesc="Game" periodwagercutoff="2012-12-12T17:10:00-08:00" store="DEPOSIT" favoredteam="Oklahoma City Thunder">
            <spread points="-14.5" team1adj="-110" team2adj="-110" puckline="" circled="N"/>
            <total points="195.5" team1adj="-110" team2adj="-110" circled="N"/>
            <money team1line="1400" team2line="-2400" drawline="0" circled="N"/>
            <popularity index="8"/>
        </line>
    </game>
    <game id="48037944" sporttype="Basketball" league="NBA" gamedate="2012-12-12T17:05:00-08:00" gamedow="4" status="O" team1rotnum="719" team1name="Dallas Mavericks" team1pitcher="" team2rotnum="720" team2name="Boston Celtics" team2pitcher="" ontv="Y" channel="ESPN" order="5">
        <line periodnum="0" perioddesc="Game" periodwagercutoff="2012-12-12T17:10:00-08:00" store="DEPOSIT" favoredteam="Boston Celtics">
            <spread points="-6" team1adj="-110" team2adj="-110" puckline="" circled="N"/>
            <total points="197.5" team1adj="-110" team2adj="-110" circled="N"/>
            <money team1line="200" team2line="-240" drawline="0" circled="N"/>
            <teamtotals team1points="94.5" team1adj1="-115" team1adj2="-115" team2points="100.5" team2adj1="-115" team2adj2="-115" circled="N"/>
            <popularity index="7"/>
        </line>
    </game>
    <game id="48037945" sporttype="Basketball" league="NBA" gamedate="2012-12-12T17:05:00-08:00" gamedow="4" status="O" team1rotnum="721" team1name="Washington Wizards" team1pitcher="" team2rotnum="722" team2name="Houston Rockets" team2pitcher="" ontv="N" channel="" order="5">
        <line periodnum="0" perioddesc="Game" periodwagercutoff="2012-12-12T17:10:00-08:00" store="DEPOSIT" favoredteam="Houston Rockets">
            <spread points="-10.5" team1adj="-110" team2adj="-110" puckline="" circled="N"/>
            <total points="206" team1adj="-110" team2adj="-110" circled="N"/>
            <money team1line="525" team2line="-750" drawline="0" circled="N"/>
            <popularity index="11"/>
        </line>
    </game>
    <game id="48037946" sporttype="Basketball" league="NBA" gamedate="2012-12-12T18:05:00-08:00" gamedow="4" status="O" team1rotnum="723" team1name="Memphis Grizzlies" team1pitcher="" team2rotnum="724" team2name="Phoenix Suns" team2pitcher="" ontv="N" channel="" order="5">
        <line periodnum="0" perioddesc="Game" periodwagercutoff="2012-12-12T18:10:00-08:00" store="DEPOSIT" favoredteam="Memphis Grizzlies">
            <spread points="-6.5" team1adj="-110" team2adj="-110" puckline="" circled="N"/>
            <total points="196" team1adj="-110" team2adj="-110" circled="N"/>
            <money team1line="-260" team2line="220" drawline="0" circled="N"/>
            <popularity index="10"/>
        </line>
    </game>
    <game id="48037947" sporttype="Basketball" league="NBA" gamedate="2012-12-12T19:35:00-08:00" gamedow="4" status="O" team1rotnum="725" team1name="San Antonio Spurs" team1pitcher="" team2rotnum="726" team2name="Utah Jazz" team2pitcher="" ontv="Y" channel="ESPN" order="5">
        <line periodnum="0" perioddesc="Game" periodwagercutoff="2012-12-12T19:40:00-08:00" store="DEPOSIT" favoredteam="San Antonio Spurs">
            <spread points="-3.5" team1adj="-110" team2adj="-110" puckline="" circled="N"/>
            <total points="209.5" team1adj="-110" team2adj="-110" circled="N"/>
            <money team1line="-165" team2line="145" drawline="0" circled="N"/>
            <teamtotals team1points="106.5" team1adj1="-115" team1adj2="-115" team2points="103" team2adj1="-115" team2adj2="-115" circled="N"/>
            <popularity index="2"/>
        </line>
    </game>
</livefeedlines>
```

//<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<(FLASH AS3 CODE)

```
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.text.TextField;

// http://feeds.justbet.cx/xml/getLiveFeedLines.asp?fromminutes=5&periods=0&scores=N&popindex=Y&leagues=nba
var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
//var url:String = "sports.xml";
var url:String = "http://feeds.justbet.cx/xml/getLiveFeedLines.asp?fromminutes=5&periods=0&scores=N&popindex=Y&leagues=nba";
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var xDoc:XMLDocument = new XMLDocument();
var statsArray:Array = new Array();
var team1:Array = new Array();
var team2:Array = new Array();

//statsArrary.length = 0;  // removes ALL data from the array


tf.tabStops = [180, 240];


urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeLoader);
urlLoader.load(request);

function completeLoader(e:Event): void {
    xDoc.ignoreWhite = true;
    var ldr:URLLoader = e.currentTarget as URLLoader;
    var xmlDP:XML = new XML(ldr.data);
    xDoc.parseXML(xmlDP.toXMLString());
    statsArray = xDoc.childNodes[0].childNodes;

    // trace("xml= " + xmlDP.game[0].@team1name);
    var maxLine:Number = statsArray.length - 1;
    for(var i:Number = 0; i < maxLine; i++) {
        team1[i] = xmlDP.game[i].@team1name;
        team2[i] = xmlDP.game[i].@team2name;
    }

    bindStats();
}

function bindStats() {
    txtGames.tabEnabled = true;
    txtGames.defaultTextFormat = tf;
    txtGames.text = "Games for Dec. 13\n\n";
    for(var i:uint = 0; i < team1.length; i++) {
        txtGames.appendText(team1[i] + "\t vs. \t" + team2[i] + "\n");  //Displayed info
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.text.TextField;

// http://feeds.justbet.cx/xml/getLiveFeedLines.asp?fromminutes=5&periods=0&scores=N&popindex=Y&leagues=nba
var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
var url:String = "sports.xml";
//var url:String = "http://feeds.justbet.cx/xml/getLiveFeedLines.asp?fromminutes=5&periods=0&scores=N&popindex=Y&leagues=nba";
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var xDoc:XMLDocument = new XMLDocument();
var statsArray:Array = new Array();
var allData:Array = new Array();

//statsArrary.length = 0;  // removes ALL data from the array

tf.tabStops = [180, 240];

urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeLoader);
urlLoader.load(request);

function completeLoader(e:Event): void {
    xDoc.ignoreWhite = true;
    var ldr:URLLoader = e.currentTarget as URLLoader;
    var xmlDP:XML = new XML(ldr.data);
    xDoc.parseXML(xmlDP.toXMLString());
    statsArray = xDoc.childNodes[0].childNodes;

    // trace("xml= " + xmlDP.game[0].@team1name);
    var maxLine:Number = statsArray.length - 1;
    for(var i:Number = 0; i < maxLine; i++) {
        allData[i] = {
            team1_name: xmlDP.game[i].@team1name,
            team2_name: xmlDP.game[i].@team2name,
            spread: xmlDP.game[i].line.spread.@points,
            total: xmlDP.game[i].line.total.@points         
        }
    }

    bindStats();
}

function bindStats() {
    txtGames.tabEnabled = true;
    txtGames.defaultTextFormat = tf;
    txtGames.text = "Games for Dec. 13\n\n";
    for(var i:uint = 0; i < allData.length; i++) {
        txtGames.appendText(allData[i].team1_name
                            + "\t vs. \t"
                            + allData[i].team2_name
                            + " (spread "
                            + allData[i].spread
                            + ") ( total "
                            + allData[i].total
                            + ")\n");  //Displayed info
    }

}
```

Enjoy!

1. Many arrays such `team1`, `team2` etc combined into one array `allData` of Objects contained complete info of one game
2. Getting data from XML with Flash abilities ( http://www.nbilyk.com/e4x-example )